# Angular 2 Custom Control link to ngControl with Control Value Accessor, Combo Date Picker

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to build a combo date picker in Angular 2, which maps a date to three dropdown lists, one for day, one for month and and one for year.

I am following the below excellent article for basic understanding:

```
http://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel
```

In the above example the author is linking it to 1 control i.e.

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onTouched()">
```

In my case instead of

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" (blur)="onTouched()">
```

I have:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="day">
<option *ngFor="let item of days" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="month">
<option *ngFor="let item of months" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="year">
<option *ngFor="let item of years" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

With single control as in the article example everything works fine since there is two way binding with [(ngModel)]="value" so when text field value is updated the changes are reflected when I access it in my html page using

```
{{ myform.controls.mydate.value }}
```

But I am not sure how do I achieve it with three dropdowns? I mean if any of the dropdown is changed, {{ myform.controls.mydate.value }} should show updated value.

I also tried adding (ngModelChange)="onDateChange()", where onDateChange function sets value of _value by composing a new date depending on selected value in drop down. But this doesn't work.

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Can you please post the solution to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom `ControlValueAccessor` for the component (`ComboDatePickerComponent`) that contains the view (HTML) from your question. In `writeValue()` or `onTouched()` you can set and read the values of the three individual input elements.